# How to direct a comment at a non-OP bounty setter?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty, comment-replies

If another user besides the OP has set a bounty, and he hasn't commented on the original question, how to direct a comment specifically at him? The @username shortcut doesn't show his name. I need clarification on his bounty requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case for bounties, but for edits, if you type an @reply to a non-OP editor, it won't suggest their name but it will still ping them. Might be the same here.

Comment: Well, hope they left a comment...

Comment: Find something else they posted (Q/A), ping them there requesting a comment, on the bountied question, for clarification.

Comment: @pnuts The bounty setter has specific requirements outside the accepted answer. The original question was answered a long time ago and doesn't apply to him. I've seen bounties set like this before too.

Comment: @BillWoodger Wouldn't a comment in another Q or A be off topic and unfortunately get flagged?

Comment: With the millions upon millions of comments which needn't remain on the site, I think you've a good chance of getting in contact. If really concerned, choose an old post on a little-viewed question. Making a comment on that won't make the post more visible, and you'd have a minute, absolutely minute, chance that someone would flag it for removal. Even then a moderator may dismiss the flag, with no evidence that the intended recipient has seen it. Give it a go, why not?

Comment: Thank you everyone. Some 1-rep left a godawful answer and the BP (bounty poster?) left a sarcastic remark. lol. Is this side-band commenting thus the accepted method in these cases? Feature request to include the @bountyposter in his bountied questions?

Comment: I'm confused. We can set bounties asking different questions from the original one? Why not just ask a new question and put a bounty on that?

Comment: I hate those type of bounties.  If the question is older and has answers, it is difficult to know how those are insufficient if the Bounty Provider doesnt monitor activity (or is not seen for days at a time). I should think that @theirname should get activated for that Q once they post they offer the bounty

Comment: @pnuts You have been patient, so the post in question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript/ You are all gifted, so I had to get my solution in fast and first. ;) The original question with the new bounty is astonishingly 5 years old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I offered a bounty on another persons question and was notified when a comment mentionning my @username was posted [link to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive#comment49096300_30441122) (I hadn't commented before) but I wasn't notified for other comments.

I can also see that comment in the responses tab on my profile page.

Comment: That's correct. Bounty setters will be notified when using @username, although auto completion doesn't list them.

Comment: Splendid. Oh, "Bounty setters"... this is going to kick up some dust over at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295823/what-is-the-term-for-the-person-offering-the-bounty