# What is the term for "the person offering the bounty"?

Tags: discussion, bounty, terminology

It's either going on here, or on English, but here goes:

What is the term for "the person offering the bounty"? I've been through the [bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounty_%28reward%29), but still don't know. Some ideas:

- Bounty setter
- Bounty offerer
- Bounter
- Bounty poster (BP as opposed to OP)

Hope this is a useful question. I'm finding it difficult to talk about this person in the 3rd-person in a [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295787/how-to-direct-a-comment-at-a-non-op-bounty-setter) MSO question. Looking for a standardized term we can all agree on(?)

(*Note:* I didn't suggest *Bounty hunter* because that would be all of us)

Comment: "Person offering the bounty" or "bounty poster" works for me.

Comment: So we need to establish the correct 1337 speech abbreviation for _"Bounty poster"_? Use any of your proposals but _"BP"_ to be clear.

Comment: _@Drakes_ /OT As from your profile: _"Some days I realize that I'm related to a **monkey** as his father's brother."_ Don't forget about the Neanderthals and the Australopithecae ...

Comment: If you actually start working on the bounty, it's *the person who made you an offer you couldn't refuse*.

Comment: Bounty offerrer. Now try saying it fast.

Comment: Being serious now, **bounty poster** is probably a good choice, as that person has posted a bounty.

Comment: @slugster **BO**, **BP** you mean?? Is that established in any way? (Remember BP was spilling the mexican gulf regions with oil all over, that would have a baad acceptance ;-) )

Comment: You guys are a riot tonight. Someone (maybe @slugster) throw up "Bounty poster" and an abbreviation (BP?) as an answer kindly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I wouldn't worry about the connotations of the abbreviation. I always avoid BP, they're always the first to raise their gas prices and last to lower them (in my region at least).

Comment: *Sponsor* sounds good to me.

Comment: I am going to use *Bountifier* from now on!

Comment: All in favour of "bounter" and "bountee" say *Ay*! (Have fun distinguishing between "bountee" and "bounty" in verbal conversation... *"Bountee-ee-ee"*)

Comment: @DavidG: No, it clearly is *bountytioner.*

Comment: Alternatively we could call them *Master of the bounty, bringer of reputation, lord of altruism and benefactor of white knights*. Obviously we shorten that to MOTBBORLOAABOWK.

Comment: Definitely! MOTBBORLOAABOWK sounds good and is easy to remember!

Comment: How about “Bountier”? Sounds French, so it’s okay, right?

Comment: Commissioner????

Comment: Given that sheriffs are usually the one offering bounties... ;-)

Comment: How about _desperate_? ;)

Comment: BO is already a commonly used abbreviation for [other things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_odor)

Comment: If only there was a [site where you could ask language related questions](http://english.stackexchange.com) ;)

Comment: (Warning: Non-native speaker's opinion follows.) How about **backer**? [ *noun* 1. a person who supports or aids a person, cause, enterprise, etc.]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The English word "benefactor" seems appropriate, particularly since there is [already a badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/221/benefactor) by that name.

> **ben·e·fac·tor**
>   ˈbenəˌfaktər/ - *noun*
>   a person who gives money or other help to a person or cause.

The "other help" being the donation of rep points, and the "cause" is increased attention.

Comment: Well, right by terms, but hard to get correctly achieved by anyone.

Comment: We have a Benefactor badge for people raising bounty on questions not of their own.

Comment: @nhahtdh Actually, the bounty on _someone else's_ post is the _Altruist_ badge.  But you're right, there's a _Benefactor_ badge for manually awarding a bounty on your _own_ question.  So that makes it a bit more official. Thanks.

Comment: I remember the name but didn't double check the definition. XD

Comment: Would we abbreviate that as _the B_ or _the BF_?

Comment: @Drakes, you asked for a term, not an abbreviation.  Personally, there are enough abbreviations and acronyms in my day-to-day life that I'm perfectly happy typing out "benefactor" in full.  :-)  [Edit: I suppose you could abbreviate it _BB_ for "bounty benefactor", but I doubt that would be obvious to anyone.]

Comment: One naturally follows from the former. If benefactor, then the BF would probably result.

Comment: Why is this answer getting downvoted? It's logical. I appreciate the thought that went into it.

Comment: "Sponsor" or "patron" might also be appropriate.

Comment: @Drakes We really don't need any more abbreviations around here. It only serves to make the site impenetrable to newcomers. No one's talking about bounties so often that they can't afford to type "benefactor" or "bounty poster" out.

Comment: Yeah, I think "sponsor" makes the most sense. A benefactor implies a recipient of beneficence, but until the bounty is awarded there is no such person. (Yeah, I see "cause" is also mentioned in the definition, but that's not how I normally think of it being used.) "Bounty Sponsor" also creates the nice acronym "BS"

Comment: What about the [Combine](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Combine)?

Comment: I disagree with this answer (and downvoted). The FBI puts bounties out for fugitives, but I wouldn't call the FBI a benefactor.

Comment: I downvoted because confusing the general term and the badge for a very similar thing is a terrible, terrible idea. "Benefactor" means *the badge of that name that we have for bounties*, not *the person who offers a bounty*.

Answer (score 20):

The **[Bligh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Bligh#The_voyage_of_the_Bounty)**. He, for better or worse, is captain of the Bounty.

Answer (score 7):

Personally I like **[Investor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/219/investor)**, same reasoning as [Benefactor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295825/1947286), but it doesn't sound as formal.

> Investor - First bounty you offer on another person's question.

---

> An investor is someone who provides (or invests) money or resources
>   for an enterprise, such as a corporation, with the expectation of
>   financial or other gain.

Comment: Investor sounds more formal than Benefactor to me. An investor is someone looking for a return and likely to have a formal contractual relationship. A benefactor is someone who does it without expectation of anything in return.

Comment: @Klors people often take out bounties with expectation of getting new answers.

Comment: Indeed, that would be a reason not to use benefactor. It doesn't make benefactor sound more formal than investor though.

Comment: @Klors perhaps "formal" isn't the right word... When I think of benefactor I tend to think of wealthy person who leaves a large endowment/trust to a museum or hospital. Sort of like high society philanthropy. Investor sounds a little lower key, like "I'll pitch in a few dollars to help get this thing off the ground..."

Comment: Investor to me sounds like a Venture Capitalist with contracts and business arrangements and other such formalities involved. With benefactor I tend to think of anonymous donation first. Perhaps that's just my romantic naivety showing through.

Comment: @Klors Perhaps using benefactor would encourage a more altruistic approach to the subject.

Comment: Note: I'm not trying to say Investor is the worse term for this person, merely noting on the formality not being a factor for me... investor and benefactor are both terms that could describe the bounty poster

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest that your option of **Bounty Poster** (abbreviated as BP) is a good option.

It's short, sweet, easy to understand, and pretty much semantically correct - the user has *posted* a bounty on the question, making them the *bounty poster*.

Comment: No one understands **BP** here really, besides of that oil company that spilled all over the Mexican gulf's coasts!

Comment: Ok, forget the BP abbreviation, but Bounty Poster is very clear and easy to understand.

Comment: Yes, I don't see why it's accruing downvotes, it's a pretty good term

Answer (score -3):

There are two kind of people who offer bounties, either the poster of the questions or someone else who was not the poster.

For both we have names **OP** for the original questioner, and [Altruist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/48/altruist), based on the badge, for anyone else.

In case you might want to distinguish the OP in the particular role (s)he was working at you should do so with some context. Which you often will have anyway: Q: "Who offered the bounty?", A: "The OP"

Answer (score -5):

I don't believe there's a commonly established abbreviation used to refer to the user running a bounty.

So instead of trying to introduce something new and uncommon like *"BP"*, be clear in your post, and use any of your other proposals to address them appropriately and readable.

---

I have to resume a bit about *"use any of your other proposals"*:

> - Bounter

is seriously out of choice, that's not a valid english word. You probably meant something like 
*"**Bounty Offerer**"*.

Abbreviation as **BO** is certainly not useful or readable though.

Comment: I figured if Scrabble [opened the floodgates](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2015/may/21/official-scrabble-book-adds-lotsa-ridic-new-words) on unorthodox words, who are we to at least not be creative.

Comment: @Drakes Well the 1st association I would have with _"bounter"_ , actually is [mutineer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutineer), which is certainly not appropriate to express what you want to express. I'm not a native english speaker though, and my sensors of reception may be twisted.

Comment: A bounty hunter is a person who scans the featured questions tab to answer them and get as many bounties awarded as possible.

Comment: @Bergi THX for pointing out, _Bounty Hunter_ doesn't really apply, you're right. Had too much wild west django unchained input recently :-P ...

Answer (score -6):

The person that has agreed to pay the bounty is the customer/client. That shortens to BC (which seems available now that Before Current Era (BCE) has replaced BC in my vocabulary.)

Comment: And, as we all know, "BC" has likewise been replaced in *everyone's* vocabulary. Wait.

Answer (score -11):

**Placer of the bounty** seems most appropriate.